# OperationContext.Current and InstanceContextMode in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to access the request header information from the `OperationContext.Current`, will it be safe to assume that if the WCF service is have thousands of calls things will not be mixed up and `OperationContext.Current` will always have the actual request header regardless of the `InstanceContextMode` whether it is `PerSession`, `PerCall` or `Single`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OperationContext.Current is the context for the current thread, so yes, it's safe.

Comment: but in `Single` mode, there is only one thread for all calls, right?

Comment: @HaLaBi, InstanceContextMode.Single just means that a single instance of your service class will be used to service concurrent requests.  So that any fields in your class will be shared between all callers.  But it doesn't impact OperationContext.Current...

Comment: @HaLaBi, Perhaps you're thinking of ConcurrencyMode, which affects threading of service calls.  But whataver you use here, you can rely on OperationContext.Current.